# Unparseable Date In America/Mazatlan timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm on `America/Los_Angeles` TZ, and when I try to render midnight in the `America/Mazatlan` TZ, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12:00 AM"
```

Here is my code to reproduce this:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Mazatlan");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    Date parse = dateFormat.parse("12:00 AM");
```

I'm aware the commenting out the `setLenient(false)` will fix the issue, I'm just not sure why that is a fix as other timezones in the same offset, such as `America/Inuvik` do not cause issues like this.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Found several other TZ's that this happens to:
`America/Hermosillo`,`Mexico/BajaSur`,`America/Bahia_Banderas`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't specify a date, 1970-01-01 is used.

The [time zone definition for Mazatlan](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014j/northamerica#L2410-L2420) shows that the base offset switched from -08:00 to -07:00 in 1970.  This creates a discontinuity in local time, similar to the kind usually found during a [spring-forward daylight saving time transition](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

There is an hour of missing local time, from midnight to just before 1:00.  Times in this range are invalid.  Assuming the zone definition is correct, that means the clocks ticked forward like this:

```
======== UTC =======     ==== America/Mazatlan ===
1970-01-01T07:59:57Z     1969-12-31T23:59:57-08:00
1970-01-01T07:59:58Z     1969-12-31T23:59:58-08:00
1970-01-01T07:59:59Z     1969-12-31T23:59:59-08:00   
1970-01-01T08:00:00Z     1970-01-01T01:00:00-07:00  (transition!)
1970-01-01T08:00:01Z     1970-01-01T01:00:01-07:00
1970-01-01T08:00:02Z     1970-01-01T01:00:02-07:00
```

Therefore, if you are using `SimpleDateFormat` - you should include a date, not just a time.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for informing me of this, seems like an odd thing.  That makes sense, as testing 12:15 AM also failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the line,

```
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

Your parse object value is becoming

```
     Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 EET 1970
```

I don't know why but for `America/Mazatlan TZ` this line is creating exception.

For `America/Los_Angeles TZ` and `America/Inuvik TZ`, usage of `dateFormat.setLenient(false)` line not giving any error and results are the same with `America/Mazatlan TZ`.

```
    Thu Jan 01 10:00:00 EET 1970
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to state that I am aware that the lenient causes an issue, I was hoping for a reason why setting it to false causes an issue.

Answer (score -1):

That because you `dateFormat.setLenient(false);` and 12:00 should be 'PM' not 'AM'

Comment: Why would it make a difference in this timezone? Others don't have an issue with it as is, only `America/Mazatlan`

Comment: @Nicholas, I don't know trying understand this by reading source code

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to understand why it's behaving so weirdly with this one timezone when I cannot see anything unusual with it.