# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1991-04-14 00:00:00"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

When I set the lenient mode to false, the excetion occurrs: "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1991-04-14 00:00:00"".
The codes as follow:`

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    format.setLenient(false);
    System.out.println(format.parse("1991-04-14 00:00:00"));
```

And when I set the lenient mode to true, the result shows:"Sun Apr 14 01:00:00 CDT 1991". 
By rights, it should be "Sun Apr 14 00:00:00 CDT 1991".

The dates below also has this problem.

- 19400603000000
- 19410316000000
- 19860504000000
- 19870412000000
- 19880410000000
- 19890416000000
- 19900415000000
- 19910414000000

Comment: I get the timezone:sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Shanghai",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=19,lastRule=null]

Comment: I would have thought about daylight saving; start of summer time. That would explain the 1 hour difference; the one second that jumps an hour.

Comment: Related: [Unparseable Date In America/Mazatlan timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302793/unparseable-date-in-america-mazatlan-timezone).

Comment: As an aside, why are you using the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), is so much nicer to work with (not that it can introduce times that don’t exist in your time zone, fortunately).

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/china/shanghai. Try choosing 1925 – 1949, 1980 – 1989 and 1990 – 1999 in the “Time zone changes for” box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the dates in the question occur in the spring. They probably occur at the transition to daily savings time in the timezone you are using.

```
format.parse("1991-04-14 00:00:00")
```

fails probably due to the fact that the timezone you are using transitioned to daily savings time on `1991-04-14 00:00:00`, which means there was no valid `1991-04-14 00:00:00` date, and instead the time jumped one hour forward, directly to `1991-04-14 01:00:00`.

As I suspected, here's the Time Change 1991 in China:

> Apr 14, 1991 - Daylight Saving Time Started
>
> When local standard time was about to reach
> Sunday, April 14, 1991, 00:00:00 clocks were turned forward 1 hour to
> Sunday, April 14, 1991, 01:00:00 local daylight time instead.

([Source](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/china?year=1991))

Therefore `1991-04-14 00:00:00` was never a valid time in China.

You can use the provided link to search for the other invalid dates. Just change the year in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If I execute your given code, I have no problem and I get the following result:

```
Sun Apr 14 00:00:00 CEST 1991
```

So maybe the problem is about your timezone ?

Comment: I get the timezone:sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Shanghai",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=19,lastRule=null]

Comment: Can you try with adding this line:

        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));

Comment: Please, [Are “Your code works fine for me” answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable) Rather post this as a comment, also when it means you will have to leave out the image.

Comment: It doesn't work for me! It prints this:Sun Apr 14 07:00:00 CDT 1991

Comment: I don't really understand if it's a good think, but you can try this: format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));

Comment: It also doesn't work! I hava tried other timezones,like GMT+8,GMT+5.  I get the reason now. You can see  Eran's answer.Thank you all the same.